# OneDrive service keeps stopping on Ubuntu on Raspberry Pi

Tags: server, services, raspberrypi, sync, cloud

I have installed a OneDrive client onedrive v2.4.22-1+np1 (https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive) on an Ubuntu server (Ubuntu 22.04.1) which is running on a Raspberry Pi 4.

After installation I have started the service via

```
systemctl --user enable onedrive
systemctl --user start onedrive
```

Synchronization with OneDrive works as expected as long as I'm logged in. When I leave the system alone it stops synchronization after some time. There is another service running on the system which relies on the synchronization. This service works still fine but produces outdated results due to lacking synchronization and the results are not visible in the cloud.

When I login into the server on the Raspberry via SSH and get the service status via `systemctl --user status onedrive` right after login, I can see that the onedrive client started just after my login while it should have been running continuously without my login:

```
Dec 14 12:45:27 raspi-server onedrive[19550]: Configuration file successfully loaded
Dec 14 12:45:27 raspi-server onedrive[19550]: Notification (dbus) server not available, disabling
Dec 14 12:45:28 raspi-server onedrive[19550]: Configuring Global Azure AD Endpoints
Dec 14 12:45:29 raspi-server onedrive[19550]: Initializing the Synchronization Engine ...
Dec 14 12:45:29 raspi-server onedrive[19550]: Initializing monitor ...
Dec 14 12:45:29 raspi-server onedrive[19550]: OneDrive monitor interval (seconds): 300
Dec 14 12:45:29 raspi-server onedrive[19550]: Starting a sync with OneDrive
```

According to the documentation at https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/USAGE.md#how-to-run-a-user-systemd-service-at-boot-without-user-login I should install the service using commands `systemctl --user enable onedrive` and `systemctl --user start onedrive`, but with `su - root` first. I get an authentification error using `su - root`. If I do it without elevated rights, the synchronisation works but stops when I'm not logged in. If I use `sudo systemctl --user enable onedrive` instead of using `su - root`, I get the error message `Failed to connect to bus: $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS and $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not defined (consider using --machine=<user>@.host --user to connect to bus of other user)`. The linked documentation deals with a similar error message, and for Ubuntu on Raspberry Pi the first step according to the documentation is *"Create a symbolic link from /home/root/.config/onedrive pointing to /root/.config/onedrive/"*. But I have neither a directory */home/root/* nor */root/.config/*, so I'm stuck here.

I don't know how to figure out what's wrong with my service configuration. How can I make the onedrive service to work continuously?

Edit:

The missing piece was the terminal command
`loginctl enable-linger <your_user_name>`
which I took from the accepted answer point 4. With this, it now works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclosure:** I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

> If I do it without elevated rights, the synchronisation works but stops when I'm not logged in.

The correct process to do this is below:

1. Login as a non-root user.
2. Configure the application for your requirement and validate it is working using --synchronize --dry-run for a 1 time sync
3. Enable and start the service required for your non-root user as per https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/USAGE.md#onedrive-service-running-as-a-non-root-user-via-systemd-with-notifications-enabled-arch-ubuntu-debian-opensuse-fedora

   `systemctl --user enable onedrive; systemctl --user start onedrive`
4. Enable your user account to linger as per https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/USAGE.md#how-to-run-a-user-systemd-service-at-boot-without-user-login

   `loginctl enable-linger <your_user_name>`

This is the correct process to use and has been validated many times.

Additionally, in future, please raise a discussion point here: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/discussions to ask questions like this.